# CopyToRealm - Value already exists: null

Tags: android, retrofit, realm

I am getting a bunch of users from my API. When I get these users, I delete any existing ones and save the new ones. I am using `Android Priority Job Queue` and `Retrofit2` to make the request.

```
    if (searchResponse != null && searchResponse.getUsers() != null)
    {
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction()
        {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm)
            {
                RealmResults<User> users = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("isOwnUser", false).findAll();
                users.deleteAllFromRealm();
                realm.copyToRealm(searchResponse.getUsers());
            }
        });
    }
```

All of the users have ID's populated from the API. But when I do the `realm.copyToRealm(searchResponse.getUsers());` I get: `io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this method to solve this problem

```
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(searchResponse.getUsers())
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works but is a bad solution since it is hiding your underlying problem:

**You have objects that have the primary key field set to null. It's probably an object that extends `RealmObject`, is in the `User` object and not annotated with `@Ignore`.**

Here's an example of what might be happening:

Let's say your `User` object contains an object `ContactInfo` that has a field `phoneNumber` that is set to be the primary key.

Some `User` objects have the `phoneNumber` field of `ContactInfo` set to null.

When you use `copyToRealm`, Realm tries to add all of `User` objects and also all `ContactInfo` objects that those `User` objects contain. Some of these `ContactInfo` objects will have the primary key field set to null. This will work for the first time since primary key fields of type `String`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer` and `Long` can be null. But when you do it for the second time, you will be breaking the primary key constraint.

Using `copyToRealmOrUpdate` will work because you will just update the existing `ContactInfo` objects with the primary key set to null. You can see that this is not what you intended to do and you'll need to ensure all of the objects you are adding to Realm have proper primary keys.